# Python: convert snmp timeticks to seconds/days, etc

Tags: python, snmp

I am using pysnmp to do an SNMP poll of some network devices.  The uptime is returned as a timeticks value, which is 1/100 second.  How do you convert timeticks to days/hours/seconds, etc?

```
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (197740964) 22 days, 21:16:49.64
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found my own answer.

```
>>> ticks = 197740964
>>> seconds = ticks/100
>>> datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
datetime.timedelta(22, 76609)
>>> print datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
22 days, 21:16:49
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that on a Windows Vista machine I'm getting the ticks in milliseconds (seconds = ticks/1000), all other machines are in hundredth of a second.

Comment: `TimeTicks=197740964`
`print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(TimeTicks)/100))`

Worked for me. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From above answer, Python code that worked for me:
(row[6] contains TimeTicks)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
ticks = int(row[6])
seconds = ticks/100
up_time = timedelta(seconds=seconds)
print(row[1], ": ",  up_time)
```